# Can a weak entity have relationship with multiple strong entities?

Tags: database-design

I ran into a situation where a weak entity happens to have attributes which are primary keys in two different entities.

My situation is like:

Strong entities:

```
--Course
-Course_Num(P.K)
-Title
-Credits

--Semester
-Semester_id(P.K)
-StartDate
-EndDate
```

Now a weak entity CoursesOffered has attributes as follows

```
--CoursesOffered
  -Course_Num
  -Semester_id
  -Instructor_Name
```

So my question is, can this weak entity have identifying relationship with above two strong entities, since the courses offered will be depending on the rows of two strong entities. Please help I am stuck if this would be correct.

Comment: If only one instructor may be related to (Course, Semester) pair which is unique then everything looks safe. Except not `Instructor_Name` but `Instructor_id` which is referenced to Instructors table.

Comment: In this course http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~donnie/dbcourse/intro0607/lectures/ more precisely in the PDF slides for lecture 17 "Converting E-R Diagrams to Relational Model" there is an example of a "weak" entity owned jointly between two "strong" ones.